# Time scale for emission process

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics

In the current approach of QFT, we model the process of creation of a particle (say a photon or a gluon out of a quark) as "instantaneous", meaning happening at a moment in time without any neighborhood (modeled via a delta function).
To what extent is this an idealization of the real behavior of nature? Do we have any experimental evidence that this process happens with a certain duration?
Can nature behave in a way which is more similar to a 'spike' rather than a smearing function?
If this process have a certain duration - what properties does a particle has during the time it is 'in the making'?

Answer (score 2):

No. Here is how it is modelled. Quantum mechanically, there are two states. One state with 1 excitation in the A field and 0 excitations in the B field $|10\rangle$ and a second state with 0 excitations in the A field and 1 excitation in the B field $|01\rangle$. We may be in a situation where the system starts entirely in state $|10\rangle$ and transitions entirely into state $|01\rangle$. However, in the intervening time, the system is in a superposition of those two states. e.g.:

$$
|\psi(t)\rangle = \cos\left(\Omega t/2\right) |10\rangle + \sin\left(\Omega t/2\right)|01\rangle
$$

Here the transition from totally $|10\rangle$ to totally $|01\rangle$ takes a duration $t = t_{\pi} = \pi/\Omega$. However, in the intervening time, the system is in a superposition of both of the two states. Immediately after $t=0$, e.g. at $t = t_{\pi} / 100$, the system will mostly still be in $|10\rangle$, but it will have a little bit of population in $|01\rangle$.

The state of the system, seen as a vector in Hilbert space, is a continuous function of time moving from being mostly in one state (with excitation in field A but not B) to being mostly in the other state (with excitation in field B but not A). This solves the paradox of discontinuous transformations of state (something which should make any physicist bristle) but forces you to take quantum superpositions seriously.

I'm most familiar with Rabi oscillations between atoms and photons. I.e. the transition from excited electron in atom + no photon TO ground state electron in atom + a photon. In this case $\Omega$ might be a few MHz so $t_{\pi}$ is around a microsecond. But much smaller or larger coupling rates can be realized in other types of physical systems.

Comment: Interesting, but this model assumes a simple interaction. Would you say that in QED / QCD this process has a finite duration?

Comment: @Yair what do you mean “this process”

Comment: Process = a transition from a situation of having just a quark to quark with a photon (or a gluon). In QED/QCD this is considered as an event which happens without duration.

Comment: @Yair In this case the initial state is (Quark in state A + no photon) and the final state is (Quark in state B + a photon). (I'm not a particle physicist so I'm assuming this is an allowed process). The situation here is the same as described in the post. There is some coupling term that connects those two states together. If the system transitions from being entirely in the first state to being entirely in the second then (1) yes, there will be a finite duration between those two states and (2) the system will be in a superposition of both states in the intervening time.

Comment: It might well be that you are right. However, what concerns me is a situation in which the interaction is unbounded (not as in your example). Meaning, that cases in which the Hamiltonian is undefined at this particular moment. Anyway, thanks!

Comment: @Yair I don't know what an "unbounded" interaction is.